# Cannot trigger event on element in js-fixture with Karma and Mocha

Tags: jquery, mocha.js, karma-runner, mocha-phantomjs

I am using js-fixture, Mocha, Chai, Sinon with Karma.

I am able to see the correct element in wrapper.

However when I trigger the click event my click event is never triggered.

I am assuming the event is never binding to the element.

Am I doing something wrong with the fixtures? Is there a better way to test jQuery events with mocha?

Test:

```
var thisFixture,
    wrapper;
describe("modal is removed when close button is clicked", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        fixtures.path = "/base/spec/javascripts/fixtures";
        fixtures.load('modal.html');
        thisFixture = $(fixtures.body());
        wrapper = $(thisFixture[0]);
    });
    it("should is removed from the dom", function () {
        debugger;

        h2uModal.bindEvents();
        var close = wrapper.find(".fa-times");
        expect(wrapper.size()).to.equal(1);
        close.trigger("click");
        expect(wrapper.size()).to.equal(0);
    });
    afterEach(function () {
        fixtures.cleanUp();
    });
});
```

Code under test:

```
var h2uModal = {
    bindEvents: function () {
        $("#modal .fa-times").click(function () {
            $(this).parents("#wrapper").remove();
        });
    }
};
```

Fixture:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='modal'>
        <i class='fa-times'></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

```
Chrome 34.0.1847 (Mac OS X 10.9.2) modal is removed when close button is clicked should is removed from the dom FAILED
AssertionError: expected 1 to equal 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I'm seeing is how you use jQuery. You initialized `wrapper` like this:

```
wrapper = $(thisFixture[0]);
```

Then you click your `#fa-times` element, which should remove the element that you grabbed in `wrapper` from the DOM. Before the click, you test for this:

```
expect(wrapper.size()).to.equal(1);
```

So far so good, but after the click which would remove it, you test for this:

```
expect(wrapper.size()).to.equal(0);
```

It can't work. This **would** work if removing an element from the DOM would somehow update the `jQuery` objects that contain it, but this is now how `jQuery` works. If I grab a dozen paragraph elements with:

```
var $foo = $('p');
```

and do `$foo.remove()`, the size of `$foo` *will not change*. The only difference between before and after is that the DOM elements that were selected by `$foo` were with a parent node before removal and are without parent node after removal.

So you could update your code to check that `wrapper[0].parentNode` is not `null` before the click and `null` after.

By the way, the [`size()` method](https://api.jquery.com/size/) has been deprecated since jQuery 1.8, you should use `wrapper.length` if you want to test for its size (in some other test).

Comment: Louis,  I think that if this was not in Karma you would be correct.  I checked wrapper[0].parentNode before and after, but the element is still there.  The click event is not firing, I put a debug statement in the function that binds the click and jQuery is not finding that element, because it is in a iFrame, again Karma.

Comment: What I've pointed out may not be the only problem with your code but it *is* a problem.

Comment: I agree, and fixed, that but still having the issue.